# Why is Chrome reporting an old NaturalWidth for an Image object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

Right, so I'm about 99% sure this is an annoying bug in Chrome (and Edge etc.) because it works perfectly in Firefox. Anyway, I have a class that has an Image object that will change source from time to time, and I need to use the NaturalWidth and NaturalHeight properties of the image. Problem is, when the source of the image changes Chrome does not update these properties. Only with a subsequent source change will they change, and they'll change to the image prior to the currently loaded one -_-

```
class Pictura {

    constructor(target) {

        this.container = target;

        this.canvas = new Image;

        this.containerStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.container, false);

    }

    load() {
        
        this.canvas.src = this.containerStyle.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
        
        this.canvas.onload = function() {

            this.container.addEventListener('pointermove', this.pan.bind(this));

            this.container.addEventListener('pointerout', this.default.bind(this));

            this.default();
            
        }.bind(this);

    }

    pan(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.canvas.naturalWidth);
        let xPos = numberRange(e.offsetX, 0, this.container.clientWidth),
            yPos = numberRange(e.offsetY, 0, this.container.clientHeight);

        let xPercent = (this.canvas.naturalWidth > this.container.clientWidth
            ? xPos / this.container.clientWidth * 100 + '%'
            : '50%');

        let yPercent = (this.canvas.naturalHeight > this.container.clientHeight
            ? yPos / this.container.clientHeight * 100 + '%'
            : '50%');

        Object.assign(this.container.style, {
            backgroundPosition: xPercent + ' ' + yPercent,
            backgroundSize: this.canvas.naturalWidth + 'px ' + this.canvas.naturalHeight + 'px'
        });
        this.container.classList.add('static');
    }

...
```

That's the code in question. The load() method is called when the background image is changed, and then the this.canvas image object is updated with the new background image.

I've tried creating a new Image object rather than recycling the existing one, doesn't make a difference. I also tried creating a new instance of the Pictura class, and still Chrome uses the height and width properties from the previously loaded image, even though that image belonged to a completely different instance of the class.

What's going on?

Comment: Hey, could you include the part of the code that uses `naturalHeight`?

Comment: In this example 400 and 300 are logged: https://jsfiddle.net/wbmp2sLr/

Comment: added a method that uses naturalHeight

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out a way around my problem. For reasons I'm still unsure of pulling the width/height data from a Image created from sourcing it from the target backgroundimage causes problems. I've rewritten the method to get the image URL directly and now it works properly